# What is the difference between find function in Underscore(JavaScript Lib ) and normal java-script function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am using underscore function in my JavaScript Code but after deploying my site in production. I realized, normal JavaScript function take less time than underscore library`s function

What is the main difference between two of them if they are using same source(JavaScript)

1.Underscore library function

```
var value= _.find(array, function(elementInArray) {
            return elementInArray === ListOfArray;
        });
```

2.Normal JavaScript function

```
var value= array.find(function(elementInArray) {
            return elementInArray === ListOfArray;
        });
```

Comment: There is no `Array.find` method. Did you mean [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)?

Comment: Also, since underscore is written purely in JavaScript, you can easily compare the two, like-for-like ~ https://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-28

Comment: Yes it is prototype @Phil
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Yeah, that's the same link I provided. Your Pascal-cased variable names were confusing. I've fixed them up to be less so

Comment: @Phil : Can you explain bit more, what is main difference in terms of which will give better performance?

Comment: Take a look at [Why does UnderscoreJS have wrapper functions around a lot of native Javascript functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25166394/2605758), it gives a good overview of why there is overlap between _ and native JS (Hint: `Array.prototype.find()` is not compatible at all with Internet Explorer), but not necessarily why the native JS is faster.

Answer (score 4):

Underscore was written with wide browser compatibility in mind. At the time they wrote the `_.find()` method, `Array.find()` was by far not available in all browsers. It is, for example, not available in most IE versions.

Hence, there's some overhead involved in building a method that's running in all major browsers, compared to directly implementing `Array.find` in a way that's optimized for each browser's JS engine.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @fjc answer there is also another big difference between those two functions:

Native Array.find only can be used with Arrays returning a **TypeError** when you try to call it for instance:

```
con myString = 'a';
myString.find(e => e === 'a');
```

Whereas you can use underscore find with this same example and it will return **undefined** instead of throwing an error. So as first consequence you would have to be more cautious using native Array.find and adding the proper guards in your code checking that you use it calling with an Array especially with variables that are going to be dynamically instantiated